# Detecting fall with kinect

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

i have write an Algorithm for detection fall with kinect sensor. Now i elaborate i Joint Head. I calculate a distance from the floor in this view:

```
public void verificaCaduta(SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame, KinectDati_Joints joints)
        {
            if (skeletonFrame != null && joints != null)
            {
                float A = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane.Item1;
                float B = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane.Item2;
                float C = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane.Item3;
                float D = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane.Item4;

                //dovrei calcolare la distanza dal pavimento
                //joint head
                float addendo1 = A * joints.head.Position.X;
                float addendo2 = B * joints.head.Position.Y;
                float addendo3 = C * joints.head.Position.Z;

                float addendo1_d = A * A;
                float addendo2_d = B * B;
                float addendo3_d = C * C;


                float numeratore = addendo1 + addendo2 + addendo3 + D;
                float denominatore = addendo1_d + addendo2_d + addendo3_d;

                float distanza = numeratore / (float)System.Math.Sqrt(denominatore);
              //  Console.WriteLine("probabile caduta " + distanza);

                if (distanza <= 0.60)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("fall detection ?");
                }
            }
        }
```

If distance from the floor is before 0.6 i detection fall. But now i would complicate algorithm. I would calculate the distanze from the floor the all JOINT and combinate the information.

Can we help me????

Regards all

Answer (score 0):

Extract the distance calculating code into a method "DistanceFromJointToFloor", then iterate through each joint calling that new method. Compare the distance result to your threshold of 0.6f:

```
public float DistanceToFloor(SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame, Joints joint)
{
    float A = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane.Item1;
    float B = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane.Item2;
    float C = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane.Item3;
    float D = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane.Item4;

    //dovrei calcolare la distanza dal pavimento
    //joint head
    float addendo1 = A * joints.head.Position.X;
    float addendo2 = B * joints.head.Position.Y;
    float addendo3 = C * joints.head.Position.Z;

    float addendo1_d = A * A;
    float addendo2_d = B * B;
    float addendo3_d = C * C;


    float numeratore = addendo1 + addendo2 + addendo3 + D;
    float denominatore = addendo1_d + addendo2_d + addendo3_d;

    float distanza = numeratore / (float)System.Math.Sqrt(denominatore);
    return distanza;
}
```

then your modified method looks like this (note: I do not know what type KinectDati_Joints is but i assume it is a collection that you can extract joints from):

```
public void verificaCaduta(SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame, KinectDati_Joints joints)
{
    if (skeletonFrame != null && joints != null)
    {
        foreach(Joint joint in joints)
        {
            float distanza = DistanceToFloor(skeletonFrame, joint);
            if (distanza <= 0.60)
            {
                   Console.WriteLine("fall detection ?");
                   Console.WriteLine("with joint: " + joint);
                   Console.WriteLine("distance:" + distanza);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```